# How do I use AJAX to both create and edit new posts using the same html template (with Python & Django)?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I'm trying to switch to saving a form with AJAX instead of just Python/Django (I'm an absolute newb, so please forgive my idiocy). Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blurb_new, name='blurb_new'),
    path('blurb/new/', views.blurb_new, name='blurb_new'),
    path('blurb/<int:pk>/edit/', views.blurb_edit, name='blurb_edit'),
]
```

**views.py** (the relevant part):

```
@login_required
def blurb_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BlurbForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            blurb = form.save(commit=False)
            blurb.author = request.user
            blurb.save()
            return redirect('blurb_edit', pk=blurb.pk)
    else:
        form = BlurbForm()
    return render(request, 'mysite/blurb_edit.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def blurb_edit(request, pk):
    blurb = get_object_or_404(Blurb, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BlurbForm(request.POST, instance=blurb)
        if form.is_valid():
            blurb = form.save(commit=False)
            blurb.author = request.user
            blurb.last_edited_date = timezone.now()
            blurb.save()
            return redirect('blurb_edit', pk=blurb.pk)
    else:
        form = BlurbForm(instance=blurb)
    return render(request, 'mysite/blurb_edit.html', {'form': form, 'blurb': blurb})
```

**blurb_edit.html** (the relevant parts):

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" class="blurb-form">{% csrf_token %}
   <input id="blurb-name" name="title"
        {% if form.title.value != None %}value="{{ form.title.value }}"{% endif %} 
   />
   <textarea name="text" id="my-textarea">
        {% if form.text.value != None %}
            {{ form.text.value }}
        {% else %}
            Type your blurb here.
        {% endif %}
    </textarea>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Before I used AJAX, views.py was totally doing its job (except for that pesky, unwanted page refreshing).

Because I **hate** the way the page refreshed every time you saved a blurb edit, I decided to switch to using AJAX.

Here's some AJAX I added in. It works for editing a blurb, but not for creating a new blurb--presumably because **a new blurb does not have a pk yet**. I'm not sure how to fix this.

**AJAX in blurb_edit.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit', '#myform', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:'{% url 'blurb_edit' pk=blurb.pk %}', // <--- THIS "pk" isn't working if it's a new blurb
            data:{
                title:$('#blurb-name').val(),
                text:$('#my-textarea').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },

            success:function() {
                alert("yay! it worked.")
            }

        })

    });
</script>
```

So I can edit blurbs fine.

This is the **error I get when I load the home page to create a new blurb**:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'blurb_edit' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blurb/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$']
```

How can I fix this "pk" issue, so that AJAX can work like views.py was?

Again, please forgive my ignorance (and probably shitty code) here, as I am new to these things and trying to wrap my head around it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('submit', '#myform', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'blurb_edit/{{blurb.pk}}/edit/', // check this version of url
        data:{
            title:$('#blurb-name').val(),
            text:$('#my-textarea').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },

        success:function() {
            alert("yay! it worked.")
        }

    })

});
```

Comment: If I use that, the console shows this error when I try to save the form: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: show me the console error i think you need to add / like /blurb_edit/{{blurb.pk}}/edit/